# How to check if a Swift generic type is Void?

Tags: swift, generics

I have a class along these lines: `class MyClass<Input>` and I would like to check whether the `Input` type is `Void` or not inside its initializer.

I've tried a variety of things like trying to cast to `Void` (the Swift compiler allows it but tells me this always fails), or using `is`, but I'm missing something fundamental here.

How can I check whether the generic type is `Void`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this by comparing the `.self` values of the generic variable and `Void`. Here's a quick example that you can stick in a Swift playground to see it work!

```
import UIKit

class MyClass<T> {
    init() {
        if(T.self == Void.self) {
            print("Void!")
        } else {
            print("Not Void!")
        }
    }
}

// Will print Not Void
var test = MyClass<Int>()

// Will print Void
var test2 = MyClass<Void>()
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks - `Void.self` was the missing piece of the puzzle, and it totally makes sense that it would be necessary!

Comment: Is there a similar technique that works for Array types?